# Remove Failed Drive in Windows Storage Pools

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, software-raid, windows-storage-server

I am currently using Windows Server 2012 R2 with Windows Storage Pools

I have a virtual disk called "2T RAID" that is in Parity mode.

There are 8 - 2T hard drives in this virtual disk. Today one of them failed. I do not have a spare disk to replace it with.

I'm trying to get the virtual disk to come back online without replacing the disk. I have physically removed the failed hard drive and set it to "Retired" using PowerShell. This is the current state of the storage pool:
[image]

If I try to attach the virtual disk, it just fails with no real info as to why. If I try to remove "PhysicalDisk-1" I get this error:[image]

Is there anyway I can get this virtual disk to come back online without having to replace the failed hard drive?

Answer (score 2):

It is not possible to have the virtual disk come back online until a replacement hard disk has been allocated once the failed disk has been retired.

To quote [technet](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Dn782852.aspx#BKMK_Step6RemoveOldDisk):

> You can't remove a disk unless sufficient unallocated capacity and a sufficient number of disks are available to successfully repair the storage spaces that depend on the disk.

It may be possible to re-insert the failed disk and let the Storage Space rebuild on that for the time being, however it is a much better solution to wait for the replacement disk if downtime for the volume is acceptable.

To avoid this issue in the future only retire a disk once a replacement has been added to the physical system, Storage Spaces will not make use of a disk once it has been marked as failed. Full instructions and the procedure [here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Dn782852.aspx#BKMK_ReplaceFailedDisks).